# Feedback from a 100 W laser power supply

Tags: power-supply, power, laser, back-emf

I built a 100 W laser cutter from scratch using a controller from a small laser cutter I had
before (Open Builds Blackbox 4x).

It worked with no problems, but I'm going from a 7 W laser to a 100 W laser and it uses a completely different power supply. The output to the laser is 26 kV at 0.35 A.

When I send a cut to the controller it moves to the starting point, then tells the laser to turn on, sending a fault back from the controller immediately. If I send it 3 or 4 times in a row, it will start to cut for a short time and then fail again.

If I unplug the PWM to the power supply, the program runs flawlessly, just with no laser.

The 1 kΩ pot limits the overall power output depending on the size of laser you're using. It uses a 5 V reference to set the output (not in thecphotos but is installed like in thevschematic).

I cut out everything you see in the image down to the basic parts that are drawn in the schematic I provided and still have the issue.

In the overall image, in the bottom left, you can see the high-voltage end of the power supply rolled up in a coil. I had a lot extra after attaching to the laser tube and didn't want to cut it. Could that be creating some kind of feedback?

Whatever is causing the fault in the controller, it's coming from the power supply. Any thoughts?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: without examining each PS spec, its hard to say but ALL power leads should be short twisted pairs to reduce noise radiation crosstalk potential issues.  Your AC loop is large and your DC loops are too large.  Start by fixing the DC HV with a short path wrapped with ground wire.

Comment: High voltage has a nasty habit of weaseling it’s way out from connectors and I’ve even seen it tunnel through some bad potting. If your supply has output isolation or fault detection then a HV leak could be triggering it’s protection circuits. Unfortunately I could not find a manual for this unit